# Как исправить recyclerView чтобы данные отображались правильно?

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть список который отображает прикрепленные к письму файлы, этот список находится в форме написания сообщения, и по умолчанию пустой, но после того как пользователь выберет из памяти устройства один файл, список появляется и отображает прикрепленные файлы. У меня есть функция удаления элемента списка, и каждый элемент списка красиво удаляется, и сразу же список обновляется. Но есть одна проблема - после добавления файла в массив я не вижу его в списке прикрепленных файлов, но он есть в массиве прикрепленных файлов. Я уже пробовал очищать список и снова добавлять в него элементы, пробовал ничего не чистить и тогда у меня добавляется по два элемента, короче что я только не пробовал, но нормальной работы списка я не добился. Вот адаптер списка:

```
public class AttachedFileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttachedFileAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //vars
    private ArrayList<String> mNames;
    private ArrayList<Integer> mImageUrls;
    private Context mContext;

    public AttachedFileAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> imageUrls) {
        mNames = names;
        mImageUrls = imageUrls;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.attached_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImageUrls.get(position))
                .into(holder.image);

        holder.name.setText(mNames.get(position));

        holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                JsonArray array = MySingleton.getInstance().getArray();
                if (array.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                        JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                        if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).equals(mNames.get(position))) {
                            array.remove(object);
                            MySingleton.getInstance().setArray(array); // удаляем запись из источника (как я понял)
                            Log.w("MY_TAG", "success");
                        }
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    WriteResponseMess.deleteAttachment(position);
                }

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImageUrls.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView image;
        TextView name;
        Button deleteBtn;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            deleteBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_attachment);
        }


    }
}
```

вот дальше диалог по прикреплению файлов:

```
 dialog_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                        File selected = new File(curFolder, fileList.get(position));
                        if (selected.isDirectory()) {
                            ListDir(selected);
                        }
                        if (selected.isFile()) {
                            if (array.size() == 0) {
                                array = new JsonArray();
                                array = uploadFiles(array, selected.getName(), convertFileToString(selected.getPath()));
                            } else {
                                if (array.toString().contains(selected.getName())) {
                                    Toast.makeText(WriteResponseMess.this, R.string.attaching_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    array = uploadFiles(array, selected.getName(), convertFileToString(selected.getPath()));
                                }

                            }
                            finalDialog1.dismiss();

                            ms.setArray(array);
                        }


                    }
                });
```

вот дальше функция получения самого списка:

```
private void getImages() {
        mNames.clear();
        filePreview.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        AttachedFileAdapter itemArrayAdapter = new AttachedFileAdapter(WriteResponseMess.this, mNames, filePreview);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(WriteResponseMess.this));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject object =array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".txt")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_txt);
            }
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".zip")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_zip);
            }
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".html")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_html);
            }
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".pdf")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_pdf);
            }
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".doc")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_doc);
            }
            mNames.add(object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1));
            itemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(mNames));
            Integer data = object.get("data").toString().getBytes().length / 1024;
        }


    }
```

и вот функция удаления элемента:

```
public static void deleteAttachment(int adapterPosition) {
        mNames.remove(adapterPosition);
        filePreview.remove(adapterPosition);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

            JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".txt")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_txt);
            }
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".zip")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_zip);
            }
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".html")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_html);
            }
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".pdf")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_pdf);
            }
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".doc")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_doc);
            }
            mNames.add(object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
```

не могу понять где протупил и что не так сделал, потому что по логике вроде должно все работать так как нужно, но этого я не смог добиться. Надеюсь на помощь более опытных разработчиков, потому что сам я сижу уже неделю, и не могу решить возникшую проблему.

Comment: не увидел, где вы обновляете адаптер, привязанный к `RecyclerView`. Есть такая строчка?

Comment: возможно нет, я уже честно говоря все что мог перепробовал. Я так думал что сначала чистить и потом опять заполнять список, и дальше уведомлять об это адаптер - это и есть обновление адаптера. Но вероятнее всего я ошибался :)

Comment: ну чтобы изменения вступили в силу после добавления данных в массив необходимо уведомить об этом адаптер, привязанный к RV - `notifyDataSetChanged();`. Вы обновляете какой-то `adapter`, но мне почему-то кажется, что он к RV не относится). Сделайте: `itemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` после добавления данных в массив. (адаптер и RV сделайте глобальными переменными). Это навскидку.

Comment: если я правильно понял, то нужно все сделать глобальным и везде где мы влияем на список вставить уведомление адаптера? просто я вроде сделал то что вы сказали, но у меня не получается получить нормальный список, айтемы не отображаются хотя они есть.

Comment: вообще, да. Должно работать. Тогда не знаю, надо во всём коде ковыряться

Comment: короче я кажись нашел корень зла)) проблема в том что я добавляю в список файлов превью расширения файла, и из-за этого у меня страдал список, либо отказаться вообще от этой функции, либо выбрать что-то демократичное и подходящее для всех расширений)